# How to perform a calculation n amount of times?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a homework problem where we have to count the amount of rectangular blocks used in the construction of a pyramid design. The pyramid design consists of 'x' rows, 'y' columns and 'z' layers. For example if the values x = 2, y = 3, z = 1 were entered, the program would output 6, which would be the number of blocks. Every layer that comes after has one more row (x+1) and one more column(y+1). So if the values x = 2, y = 3, z = 2 were entered, 12 would be returned which is the number of total blocks and so on.

This is what I have so far but I keep getting an error:

```
def blocks(x,y,z):

if z == 1:
    return x * y
else:
    result = []            
    total = x * y #<--- initial calculation
    for i in range(z):

        total = ((x+1)*(y+1))
        result = result.append(total)

print (blocks(2,3,4))
```

The error message I get is:
     result = result.append(total)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Just use `result.append(total)`. This is little more than a typo.

Comment: Hey @JohnColeman, Thanks for the reply, was wondering if you could help me out with this last bit. I want to actually add all the outputs and give a total number of blocks. any suggestion on how to do that? for example if layer 1 had 6 blocks, layer 2 had 12 blocks and layer 3 had 20 blocks, how can I have a running total where it would give me just the output 38?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask another question about that since this particular question was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` returns `None`, so your reassignment:

```
result = result.append(total)
```

will reassign `result` to `None` on each iteration of your loop. Instead, remove the reassignment, since `append` modifys the existing list in place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was wondering if you could help me out with this last bit. I want to actually add all the outputs and give a total number of blocks. any suggestion on how to do that? for example if layer 1 had 6 blocks, layer 2 had 12 blocks and layer 3 had 20 blocks, how can I have a running total where it would give me just the output 38?

Comment: @FarhanIqbal I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can get a total from a list of integers by simply passing the list to the builtin `sum()` function: `sum(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `result = result.append(total)`

with `result.append(total)`

when you append an object to a list, there is no need to set the result equal to a new list; it does the appending on the list in place.